# How to do a continuation and include it as part of the MULTI command?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, redis, stackexchange.redis

In summary, I'm trying to call a `ITransaction.SetPopAsync(...)` and perform other write operations as part of the underlying `MULTI` Redis atomic operation.

I've tried to perform a continuation of `SetPopAsync(...)` calling `Task.ContinueWith`, and perform the so-called other write operations inside the callback, but I got surprised when I found that these are executed after the underlying `MULTI` operation ends (i.e. when `ITransaction.ExecuteAsync()` finishes).

Maybe I'm mistaken, but I feel that this atomic operation could be done only if I load a LUA script into Redis and I call it from C#.

Is there any other solution to my case that might be purely implementable in C# and `StackExchange.Redis` library?

### Further info...

I've found that there's a specific documentation about this topic [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Transactions.md).

Now I'm more confused because *what happens if you perform the whole `spop` and it's not part of the `MULTI` command, and when you're create other keys after the `spop`, the system goes down and it leaves the data corrupted?

So... Am I missing something that could let me perform the whole `spop` and be sure that all others operations are going to be done and persisted?

### A sample scenario...

As @BerinLoritsch has requested in some comment here, I'm going to throw here a **pseudo-code** using Redis commands to give an example of what's going on here:

```
MULTI
key1MemberValue = spop key1 1

sadd key2 key1MemberValue 
zadd key3 1 key1MemberValue 
EXEC
```

*Note I can't use `smove` because I don't know the set member in my real-world case. I need to pop a random one.*

Comment: Seeing a code snippet for the critical section of what you at least want to do can go a long way.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I believe that it's true that SO wants code snippets, but the issue has nothing to do with a particular case. It's more tied to the fact that a `MULT` is an atomic execution and you can't rely on write operations which return a value, to continue with that value performing other operations inside the whole `MULTI` command

Comment: @BerinLoritsch See my question's update... I've made a simple pseudo-code to give you a sample of the whole atomic operation, or at least, what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, and actually in my particular case, there's another way to solve the same issue and it allows me to do the operation with atomicity.

Instead of using `spop`, check the following pseudo-code using Redis commands:

```
time = [current time]
member = zrangebyscore key1 -inf +inf limit 0 1

zrem key1 member
zadd key2 time member
zadd key3 time member
```

For now, it seems like here the optimal solution is a LUA script which calls above code listing's commands, because since Redis is single-threaded and it can happen one operation at time and a LUA script is considered an operation itself, if I want to be sure that other operation won't try to work to pop the same `set` value, I feel this should be the way to go...

In addition, I had to turn *regular sets* into *sorted sets*. Because of Redis' constraints to avoid data corruption in replicated and clustered environments, you can't call write commands after a non-deterministic command, either if it's a read or write operation. Thanks to `zrangebyscore` (and it could be `zrange`, `zrevrange`, `zrevrangebyscore`...), since *it's deterministic*, I could simulate the *pop* operation and still use the set semantics.

Comment: What happens if another connection pops the member between `srandmember` and `multi`? You'd probably need something involving `WATCH` to do this robustly. In terms of SE.Redis, I suspect I could add a `Condition.SetContains`, which would then suffice as a pre-condition (this would become `WATCH {key}; SISMEMBER {key} {value}; MULTI; {blah}; EXEC;`, with some code to verify the result of `SISMEMBER` before the `MULTI`)

Comment: For more context on `Condition` etc: http://blog.marcgravell.com/2012/10/multiplexed-transactions-in-booksleeve.html

Comment: @MarcGravell I see. But am I wrong about my conclusion? I mean, if I run this in a LUA script using `EVALSHA`, it should be robust enough?

Comment: @MarcGravell Do you know why `multi` isn't allowed in a Lua script?

Comment: @MarcGravell Well in fact, I believe I'm doing the same as this issue https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2139, but I'm using `srandmember`, and it also drives me to the same issue, as described in some post there

Comment: @MarcGravell Argh, now I'm not sure about this. If I remove the `redis.call("multi")`, it works. It's not exactly the issue I linked above..

Comment: `multi` simply *serves no purpose* inside EVAL, since EVAL *already* has contiguous control

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, this is what I found now. Thank you anyway

Comment: @MarcGravell BTW, it seems like a write command inside the script persist the data forever, even if the script isn't completely executed. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MarcGravell Bad news... Our approach won't work in LUA. If I do a `spop`, `srandmember`, `sscan`... whatever it would let me get a set member without knowing it, it throws this error in Redis: `Write commands not allowed after non deterministic commands`

Comment: @MarcGravell See my updated answer. I've needed to turn sets into sorted sets because the issue with non deterministic commands :D

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, you need to understand that redis multi/exec blocks are not like ADO.NET transaction. Fundamentally, the following (from the question) *is not possible in redis*:

```
MULTI
key1MemberValue = spop key1 1

sadd key2 key1MemberValue 
zadd key3 1 key1MemberValue 
EXEC
```

because what you get back from `spop` is: `QUEUED`. That's all. You don't get any *answers* until the `EXEC`, so you *cannot* use this value in the `sadd`/`zadd` inside the `MULTI`.

What you *could* conceivably do, in raw redis, is something involving `WATCH`; however, all this means is that if the `WATCH`-ed key(s) are mutated by another connection, the `MULTI`/`EXEC` block is *abandoned*, not executed; you would *still* have `spop`-ped.

So fundamentally: yes, if you want this to happen without competing connections invalidating state: you will have to do it via Lua and `EVAL`/`EVALSHA` - or it would need changes to the `Condition` API.

Comment: Thanks for the effort ;) At the end of the day, since we've arrived to the same conclusion - the EVAL/EVALSHA way -, at least I feel I'm in the right track!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer it *could* also be done with `WATCH`, but Lua is probably the easiest approach to implement and get right

Comment: Yeah... Think about KISS... Right, having to load a script whenever the service starts isn't that KISS, but the solution itself is KISS anyway

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer you mention SE.Redis in the tags; if you just use `ScriptEvaluate` passing the Lua, it will automate the load etc to use `EVALSHA`

Comment: Ah, I thought I had to call `IServer.ScriptLoad` or its async counterpart, and then use `ScriptEvaluate`

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer nope; it will deal with all that stuff internally